# White space at the bottom of my cordova app on ios

Tags: ios, cordova

I've build my cordova app on a mac and end up with white space at the bottom of my app. When I switch between apps and come back the white space is gone and the app is in fullscreen mode.

I use cordova plugin splashscreen and have this in my config.xml

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
```

The splashscreen size is 2732x2732px.

App with white space after opening the first time:
[image: App with wrong layout]

App after I switch between apps and come back:
[image: App with good layout]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed the issue with these css lines:

```
html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Very Helpful. I've struggled with this bug for almost a year until I could find this q/a. Savior!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me
https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6695

remove cordova's Wkwebview plugin from your project, including cleaning your config.xml from the related entries
install the ionic webview (which includes the Wkwebview plugin + their own improvements):
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save

Answer (score -1):

**viewport-fit=cover** just add this to your meta tag in header of your main *HTML* file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Make sure you have installed status bar plugin and added below lines in config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: He is not referencing to status bar

Comment: Yes I know ... If you have status bar plugin then
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
above will work